# How to make Mail Body Text in Two lines in Windows 8 using LaunchUriAsync

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, winrt-async

Here is my Code

```
 var body="Hello World";
 var mailto = new Uri("mailto:?to=a@a.com&subject=Hello&body="+body); 
 await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(mailto);
```

I wanted to display 'Hello' in first line & 'World' in Second line.

I tried with

```
  var body="Hello" + "/n" + "World"
```

But it is not working . How can we achieve this ?

Comment: Try `\n` instead of `/n` and if that's not enough, try `\r\n`

Comment: @RogerRowland tried with both ; but not working. Any other way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var body="Hello%0D%0AWorld"
var mailto = new Uri("mailto:?to=a@a.com&subject=Hello&body=" + body); 
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(mailto);
```

You have to use `%0D%0A` in place of `\n`

Answer (score 0):

Followed by @Xyroid, more versitle method would be as below.

```
var body = "Hello" + Environment.NewLine + "World\nHere is Third Line" ;
body = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(body);
var mailto = new Uri("mailto:?to=a@a.com&subject=Hello&body=" + body); 
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(mailto);
```

Please kindly see `System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode()` method to convert some text into uri-based parameters.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

StringBuilder body= new StringBuilder();
body.AppendLine("Hello ");
body.AppendLine("World");

string mailBody=body.ToString();